# Flutter - oauth2 - Android - redirecturi not working

Tags: android, flutter, oauth-2.0

I have an issue with a flutter implementation on Android. On iOS it works fine.
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="com.mycomp.myapp"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I defined the SpotifyClient like that:

```
class SpotifyOAuth2Client extends OAuth2Client {
    SpotifyOAuth2Client({required String redirectUri, required String customUriScheme}) :
            super(
                authorizeUrl: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize',
                tokenUrl: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
                redirectUri: redirectUri,
                customUriScheme: customUriScheme) {
        this.accessTokenRequestHeaders = {'Accept': 'application/json'};
    }
}
```

And here is where I try to call the client:

```
OAuth2Client client = SpotifyOAuth2Client(
            redirectUri: 'com.mycomp.myapp://callback',
            customUriScheme: 'com.mycomp.myapp');
var authResp = await client.requestAuthorization(
            clientId: 'huhuhuhuhuhuhuhuhu',
            customParams: {'show_dialog': 'true'},
            scopes: ['user-read-private', 'user-read-playback-state', 'user-modify-playback-state', 'user-read-currently-playing', 'user-read-email']);

print(authResp.code);
```

The app is correctly triggering the authorization to Spotify. I get to log in and accept on the web browser.
Then I get redirected to myApp but nothing happens. The print(authResp.code) (and of course everything following) above never fires.

Again, on iOS I have no issue.

I have been trying many thing but with no success. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After many trials, I have been able to fix the issue.
Hope it can help somebody else.

Adding the following activity (and not only intent-filter in an existing activity) made the trick:

```
<activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity" >
  <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="com.mycomp.myapp" android:host="callback" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi can you share the code? my code no works when try to add another activity

```
<activity
       android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable">
       <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme="com.mycomp.myapp" android:host="callback" />
       </intent-filter>
       <meta-data
           android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
           android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
           />
   </activity>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).